# How to pass two-dimensional string array into a function of another class

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, compiler-errors

I have come across a little dilemma that has stumped me for the last few days.

I am working on a project, just for practice, where the objective is to prompt the user to input a word and print out (to the screen) that same word, but in large letters drawn in ASCII characters. For example, if the user typed in the word "Hello", the output would be:

```
H    H EEEEE L     L       OOO
H    H E     L     L      O   O
HHHHHH EEE   L     L     O     O
H    H E     L     L      O   O
H    H EEEEE LLLLL LLLLL   OOO
```

I created a two dimensional string array called 'letters' inside a namespace called "UpperCaseFont".  Then, I created a class called BigWord, whose purpose would be to store a user-input word, and provide several useful functions: printWord(), setWord(), getWord() etc.

Rather than storing the two-dimensional string array inside the BigWord class (which is actually what I originally intended to do, but couldn't get working), I later thought that it would be better to pass in the letters array into a function ( setAsciiFont() ) defined in BigWord and have a pointer in the BigWord class point to the address of the letters array.  This way, instead of creating a new letters array each time a new BigWord object was created, all BigWord objects could just reference the same letters array.  Saving memory and a few clock cycles too (not that it matters in a project of this size, but I still want to develop good coding habits).

However, I cannot seem to get it working.  My code is below:

The main .cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Characters.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

   BigWord b;
   char temp[20];

   cin >> temp; // prompt user for word

   b.setWord(temp);
   cout << "Your word is: " << b.getWord() << endl;

   //Set the ASCII font for the BigWord object to use 
   b.setAsciiFont(UpperCaseFont::letters);

   b.printWord();

   return 0;
}
```

The header file (Characters.h):

```
#ifndef CHARACTERS
#define CHARACTERS

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace UpperCaseFont {
    // constant; font should not be changeable
    // all characters will have 5 rows.
    const string letters[][5] = {
        {
            "    A    ",
            "   A A   ",
            "  AAAAA  ",
            " A     A ",
            "A       A"
        },
        {
            "  BBBB   ",
            "  B   B  ",
            "  BBB    ",
            "  B   B  ",
            "  BBBB   "
        },
        {
            "   CCCC  ",
            "  C      ",
            " C       ",
            "  C      ",
            "   CCCC  "
        }
    }; // not finished making all letters yet.
}

class BigWord {
private:
    int wordLength;
    char word[];

    // letters[][5] will point to the location of UpperCaseFont::letters array.
    const string* letters[][5];

    void toUpperCase(char* str);
public:

    void setWord(char w[]);

    string getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    void setAsciiFont(const string [][5]); // PROBLEM WITH THIS FUNCTION

    void printWord(void);

};

void BigWord::setWord(char* w) {
    wordLength = strlen(w);
    //    cout << "Word Length: " << wordLength << endl;
    std::copy(w, w + wordLength, word);
    BigWord::toUpperCase(word);
}

void BigWord::toUpperCase(char* str) {
    // convert a string to Upper case letters for printWord algorithm to work
    for (int i = 0; i < wordLength; i++) {
        if (str[i] > 'Z') {
            str[i] -= ('a' - 'A');
        }
    }
}

void BigWord::setAsciiFont(const string font[][5]) { // ***PROBLEM***
    letters = &font; // How can I get this to work??
}

void BigWord::printWord() {
    // print top line of all ASCII Font letters, move to next line, repeat etc.
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < wordLength; j++) {
            // subtracts 65 (ASCII 'A') to arrive at index 0 if character == A.
            cout << *letters[word[j] - 'A'][i];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}


#endif
```

When I attempt to compile this code, I get the following error:

> Characters.h:81: error: incompatible types in assignment of `const
>   std::string (**)[5]' to`const std::string*[0u][5]'

I'm fairly new to C++ (started a couple weeks ago, but I have some Java experience to back me up), and even newer to pointers, so I don't exactly know what I am doing wrong...and any googling has been to no avail.
I understand that using the name of an array will act as the pointer to the first index of that array, but how does it work with two-dimensional (or multi-dimensional) arrays?
If needed, I can write a function to convert the UpperCaseFont::letters array into a one-dimensional array if it turns out two dimensional arrays are too troublesome to deal with.

Essentially, to get down to what I'm really asking: 
How can I assign a pointer to a two-dimensional string array that has been passed into a function within a class located in a header file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that C++ doesn't support passing arrays as arguments.
When you write:

```
void setAsciiFont( std::string const font[][ 5] );
```

the compiler converts this to:

```
void setAsciiFont( std::string const (*font)[5] );
```

When you pass an array, a similar conversion occurs.

The simplest solution is just to change your variable declaration in the 
class to reflect this:

```
std::string const (*letters)[5];
```

Because of the way indexation is defined in C++, this will work exactly
as if you had the complete array as a member, i.e. `letters['n'][line]`
will pick up the right string.

And BTW: I'd pass the font as a parameter to the constructor of
`BigWord`.  That way, there's no way you can accidentally try to output
without having set it.

Comment: Thank you!  I finally got it working =).
Oh, and I took your advice to put the font parameter into the constructor of BigWord, makes a lot of sense to do so...the less error prone the code, the better =P.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays can be passed by reference. So following function,

```
void setAsciiFont(const string [][5]); // PROBLEM WITH THIS FUNCTION
```

should be (with declaring both the dimensions),

```
void setAsciiFont(const string (&letters)[3][5]); // ok
                              ^^^^ pass by reference
```

You can templatize this function, if you are not sure of the dimension always:

```
template<size_t ROW, size_t COL>
void setAsciiFont(const string (&letters)[ROW][COL]); // ok
```

Comment: The reference solution is actually quite nice: to use it effectively, however, you'll have to change the data declaration in the class to be a reference, and pass the `letters` to the constructor (IMHO preferable anyway).  And drop the template suggestion: if you don't know the dimension, you can't safely use the array anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to properly type the letters member variable. You want to assign a `const string (*)[5]` (which is what `const string [][5]` decays to) to it, so it should have this type

```
// letters[][5] will point to the location of UpperCaseFont::letters array.
const string (*letters)[5];
```

Otherwise, it should work.